# Is there any way to bypass SSP (StackSmashing Protection)/Propolice?

Tags: security, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

After some research i haven't found any paper describing method to do this (no even an unreliable one). It seems that SSP (StackSmashing Protection)/Propolice

Comment: Is this for hacking, or for your own software? Even for your own software, I can't think of a good reason to do this (performance maybe?).

Comment: Maybe he's trying to evaluate this technology for using it in his own product it and wonders if there are any known problems with it.

Comment: You're missing the last half of your last sentence.

Comment: Zifre - Knowledge of secuirty is extremely important.  If there aren't people that ask these kinds of questions then all of our secuirty work is worthless and unproven.

Answer (score 3):

Canary's are a very good security measure for protecting against some buffer overflows.   Over the years various Canary implementations have been broken and then made more secure.  What is important is that even despite advanced memory protection buffer overflows are still being exploited on Vista,  Windows 7 and Fedora 11...

One very important thing to mention is that Canary's only protect the function's call frame (which includes the mighty EIP!).   A buffer overflow can happen in another segment of memory such as the Heap,  and a canary would have no affect.  Further more an application can be hacked using a buffer overflow without ever having to overwrite an EIP.  Controlling the EIP is a very straight forward and easy method to turn a buffer overflow into a killer exploit and that is why it is the most common method of exploitation.

These exploitation methods, as well as others are gone over in great detail in [Exploiting Software: How to break code](http://www.exploitingsoftware.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I am more familar with Microsoft's GS stack protection but the two approaches [seem similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-smashing_protection).

The following blog post from Microsoft shows one example where an attacker can still take control even when stack cookies are in use (the first example should be applicable to non-Windows systems):

- http://blogs.technet.com/srd/archive/2009/03/16/gs-cookie-protection-effectiveness-and-limitations.aspx

This blog post talks about some of the upcoming improvements to stack protection:

- http://blogs.technet.com/srd/archive/2009/03/20/enhanced-gs-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Both links are dead

Answer (score 0):

If an application has an array/buffer on the stack, and uses caller-controlled index values without bounds checking, then a caller will be able to access arbitrary memory locations, and stack protection won't be able to prevent or detect it.

Comment: That is a valid attack,  sorry it is late.